# C# compare one list with part of other list

Tags: c#, performance, linq, loops

I am trying to remove unwanted images from the website. The product image folder contains more than 200000 + Images. I have a list of product codes that are inactive in a List. I have the list of file names in another list.

```
List<string> lFileList = files.ToList();
List<string> lNotinfiles = new List<string>();
foreach (var s in lFileList)
{
   var s2 = (from s3 in lProductsList 
             where s.Contains(s3.cProductCode) 
             select s3.cProductCode).FirstOrDefault();
   if (s2 == null)
   {
      lNotinfiles.Add(s);
   }
}
```

Here `lProductsList` is the list containing `ProductCodes` that are not used.
The Image list contain multiple images for the same product but the image name contains product code ( mostly it starts with and there may be _1, _2.jpg will be there.

The above code works but it takes more than 5 min for a single folder to get the Not in list. I did try  the following but that took more than 15 min.

```
var s2 = (from s3 in lProductsList 
          where s.IndexOf(s3.cProductCode) >= 0 
          select s3.cProductCode).FirstOrDefault();
```

I have tried to remove the loop all together that also didn't work.

What should be the best way to achieve this faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to: use `HashSet`, wait with `ToList` and maybe `GroupBy`.

> `HashSet` + use of `ToList`

Currently your code is in a time complexity of o(n)2 - you iterate the outer list and for each item iterate all the items of the inner list.

Change the type of the `lProductsList` from a list to a `HashSet<string>` containing codes. Finding an item in a `HashSet` is of o(1) (list is o(n)). Then when you iterate each of the times of `lFileList` to find if they are in `lProductsList` it will be in the time complexity of o(n) instead of o(n)2.

This code will show you the time difference between when using 2 lists or when using a list and a HashSet:

```
var items = (new[] { "1", "2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10" }).SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x, 10000)).ToList();
var itemsToFilterOut = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };

var efficientItemsToFilterOut = new HashSet<string>(itemsToFilterOut);

var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
var unwantedItems = items.Where(item => itemsToFilterOut.Contains(item)).ToList();
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.TotalMilliseconds);

watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var efficientUnwantedItems = items.Where(item => efficientItemsToFilterOut.Contains(item)).ToList();
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.TotalMilliseconds);
```

As for putting it in the context of your code:

```
var notInUseItems = new HashSet(from item in lProductsList
                                select item.cProductCode);

//Notice that here I am not using the materialized `lFileList`
lNotinfiles = files.Where(item => !notInUseItems.Contains(item));
```

---

> GroupBy

**Moreover** - you said that the list contains multiple items mapping to the same key. Use `GroupBy` before filtering out. Check performance of this addition:

```
watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var moreEfficientUnwantedItems = items.GroupBy(item => item)
     .Where(group => efficientItemsToFilterOut.Contains(group.Key))
     .Select(group => group.Key);
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Check your data to analyze how significant the amount of duplications it and if needed use the `GroupBy`

Comment: watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds is a much better property to access elapsedMilliseconds in this cause because TotalMilliseconds is a double while ElapsedMilliseconds is a long and will be rounded.

Comment: No problem, Just fyi ElapsedTicks will suffer the same fate since it is also a long or int64.

Comment: Make sure to .ToList() after the .select when measuring your code also :)  The deferred execution will get you there in your snippet.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, to understand the issue... I could not test it since I did got time yet to work on that project.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Do not *materialize* files `.ToList()` i.e. do not wait until *all* files are retrieved
2. Organize `NotInFiles` as `HashSet<String>` to have a better compexity `O(1)` instead of `O(N)`.

Something like this:

```
  //TODO: you have to implement this 
  prtivate static String ExtractProductCode(string fileName) {
    int p = fileName.IndexOf('_');

    if (p >= 0)
      return fileName.SubString(0, p);
    else
      return fileName;  
  }
```

...

```
  HashSet<String> NotInFiles = new HashSet<String>(
    lNotinfiles, 
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // file names are case insensitive
```

..

```
  var files = Directory 
    .EnumerateFiles(@"C:\MyPictures", "*.jpeg", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(path => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path))
    .Select(path => ExtractProductCode(path))
    .Where(code => !NotInFiles.Contains(code))
    .ToList(); // if you want List materialization
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting Your (I assume)array to a List and then do a foreach
Using [for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) directly on the array should make it at least a bit faster.

```
List<string> lNotinfiles = new List<string>();
            for(int i = 0; i < files.Count(); i++)
            foreach (var s in files)
             {
                var s2 = (from s3 in lProductsList where s.Contains(s3.cProductCode) select s3.cProductCode).FirstOrDefault();
                if (s2 == null)
                   {
                      lNotinfiles.Add(s);
                   }
             }
```